# MostFields multi_match fuzziness on all but one field

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-6

I have several different mappings for a field. I have one field that is phonetic. I would like to do a query with fuzziness, but not use fuzziness on the phonetic field.

```
...
_client.Search<JobModelSummary>(s => s
  .Index(indexName)
  .Query(q => q
    .MultiMatch(m => m
      .Query(paginationQuery.Search)
      .Type(TextQueryType.MostFields)
      .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1))
      .Fields(f => f
        .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("standard"), 3)
        .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("edge-ngram"), 2)
        .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("phonetic"))  // <--- Don't want this fuzzy
))));
```

The documentation is sparse and I am finding it difficult to peace together how this would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're performing a most fields multi_match query as above, you can achieve what you'd like by combining several match queries together

```
var indexName = "foo";
var search = "search";

var searchResponse client.Search<JobModelSummary>(s => s
    .Index(indexName)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(sh => sh
                .Match(m => m
                    .Query(search)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1))
                    .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("standard"))
                    .Boost(3)
                ), sh => sh
                .Match(m => m
                    .Query(search)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1))
                    .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("edge-ngram"))
                    .Boost(2)
                ), sh => sh
                .Match(m => m
                    .Query(search)
                    .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("phonetic"))
                )
            )
        )   
    )
);
```

which can be made slightly more succinct with using the overload operators for queries

```
client.Search<JobModelSummary>(s => s
    .Index(indexName)
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Query(search)
            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1))
            .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("standard"))
            .Boost(3)
        ) || q
        .Match(m => m
             .Query(search)
             .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1))
             .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("edge-ngram"))
             .Boost(2)
        ) || q
        .Match(m => m
             .Query(search)
             .Field(ff => ff.Name.Suffix("phonetic"))
        )
    )
);
```

Both produce

```
POST http://localhost:9200/foo/jobmodelsummary/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name.standard": {
              "boost": 3.0,
              "query": "search",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name.edge-ngram": {
              "boost": 2.0,
              "query": "search",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name.phonetic": {
              "query": "search"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The scores for each query in the should clause will be added together to provide the final `_score` for each document. With only should clauses specified, at least one has to match for a document to be considered a match.